# npm install hangs at gulp-imagemin postinstall

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-imagemin

I am building my project using **NPM** and the install process hangs.

I have narrowed it down to the **gulp-imagemin** module for gulp.

If I run

> npm install gulp-imagemin@2.3.0

it hangs at about the 5 minute mark.

If I do **"npm install --verbose"** I get a ton of output, and eventually it hangs at this :

> npm verb unsafe-perm in lifecycle true npm info postinstall
>   utf-8-validate@1.2.1 npm verb unlock done using
>   C:\Users\watkins\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_locks\utf-8-validate-d0ec860f08ac7b2c.lock
>   for
>   D:\dev\ngs-frontend-next\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
>
> > jpegtran-bin@3.0.6 postinstall D:\dev\ngs-frontend-next\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin
> >     node lib/install.js

Is this something to do with gulp-imagemin?

How would I go about resolving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Installing gulp-imagemin on Windows creates well over 10,000 files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29759705/4877927).

As the answer suggests: you're probably running on a Windows machine.

Update your nodeJS to version 5.* to get a flat dependency list to avoid the 260 char Windows path problem, see: [Why does the 260 character path length limit exist in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1880321/4877927)

Comment: i haven't yet gotten round to trying with 5.*, maybe later this week i will have time. I will let you know :)